# How to inherit log4j2.xml from parent project to child?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

This is my first use of log4j and I don't find any documentation regarding my problem.

I have a *SpringBoot* (2, and *java 8*) parent project with a **log4j2.xml** file inside it.
The *file* is like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG" monitorInterval="60">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout> 
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
        
        <File name="FileAppender" fileName="logs.log">
            <PatternLayout> 
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Inside this project I have a set of common classes for a bunch of my other projects, such as the exception handling, with a logger inside.

The dependency I have insert inside the **parent pom.xml** is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, I want that this file works inside my child project, but the **logs.log** file is never created and some logs are printed like a normal **System.out.println()**.

So I'm wondering:

1. Do I need to create also a *log4j2.xml* file inside my child project if I want to print its logs?
2. If yes, why having only the parent xml is not sufficient?
3. If yes, is the parent xml really needed? I mean, shouldn't the log4j2.xml inside the child project also capture the generated log inside the parent project?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Parent projects can only be `pom` projects: this means that they just contain a `pom.xml` file. Therefore you parent project simply can not export a `log4j2.xml` file.

You need to create a `jar` submodule (e.g. `example-logging`) and import it into every project.